# Inserting node dynamically in Complete Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I know the concept of Binary Search Tree and Complete Binary tree. Is there a way we can write insert algorithm for Complete binary search tree or I am thinking of wrong data structure?

My objective is every time we insert a node, Tree should remain complete binary search tree.

Comment: In your definition, what is a complete binary search tree (as opposed to a plain BST)? I believe what you may actually be looking for is a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Commonly referred to as either an AVL or red-black tree

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. But it will be O(N) algorithm, just rebuild tree after every insertion or deletion.

You can't do this faster than O(N) time. Because:

1) Exists only 1 complete tree with given keys.

2) You can remove or insert the minimum and you will have to change the whole tree (costs you O(N) operations).

Instead of complete search binary trees, balanced binary trees are used (like RB, AVL, Cartesian, Splay and etc.).

Comment: I will check for AVL and balanced binary tree. If you dont mind, can you please provide algorithm for my question?

Comment: "You can't do this faster than O(n) time because remove/insert the minimum changes the whole tree" isn't sufficient. (A) you can remove the minimum from any complete BST of 2^k nodes and not need to shuffle *any* nodes; (B) even if removing the minimum did always shuffle all the nodes, that would just be a lower bound on the _worst_ case, no info on the average case. But I just did an  empirical experiment: Removing _any_ node from a complete BST of 10 nodes requires moving 9.4 nodes on average. BST of 100 nodes, move 98.49 nodes on average. BST of 1000 nodes, move 999.999 nodes.